# Firefox rendering text lower than Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

My code Renders Correctly on chrome (right), but incorrectly on Firefox (left). Any hints on how to fix it?
After a refresh(zoom in/out) it will fix itself, but almost always wrong on first render.

[image]

HTML:

```
<td>
  <label class="fb" for="11">
    <div class="strokeme"> asdf    8</div>
    <input id="11" type="checkbox" name="fb" value="11">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100/780000&amp;text=%20">
  </label>
</td>
```

CSS:

```
.fb > input[type=checkbox]{
  display:none;
}
input[type=checkbox] + img{
  cursor:pointer;
  border:5px solid transparent;
  opacity:.1;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + img{
  border:5px solid #00f000;
  opacity:1;
}
.fb {
     position:relative;
}
.fb div {
    position:absolute;
    margin:4px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.strokeme
{
    color: white;
    text-shadow:
    -1px -1px 0 #000,
    1px -1px 0 #000,
    -1px 1px 0 #000,
    1px 1px 0 #000;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to style of `.fb` label

```
.fb{
// existing style ...
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Browsers having different default settings (font, body padding etc etc.) is a known issue for web designers. [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) should render it equally for everyone.